# Update database view structure in Django

Tags: django, database, view

I changed a database view from DateField to DateTimeField but when I run ./manage.py makemigrations it says "No changes detected" 
Any ideas on how to do properly update my database view?

Comment: You need to change models.py

Comment: That's what I did but the makemigrations script doesn't detect the change.

Comment: have you run './manage.py migrate' afterward?

Comment: Yep but it says "No migrations to apply."

Comment: is your app in the INSTALLED_APPS in your settings. If so try and add the app name: ./manage.py makemigrations [appname]

Comment: Yes, the app is already installed and working, I'm just changing a field on the database view from DateField to DateTimeField.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly pass the app name as argument: `python manage.py makemigrations appname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so since views are not managed, the right way to do this is by manually creating a *migration.py file and that the changes to the view there. Once that is done the makemigrations and migrate commands will pick it.